# How to execute commands optionally in background with bash?

Tags: bash, background, parallel-processing

I want to execute a set of commands *optionally* in background and with bash. Something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
BGR=""
if [ foo ] ; then
   BGR=\&
fi
cmd1 $BGR
cmd2 $BGR
cmd3 $BGR
wait
```

But this doesn't seem possible with bash. If `foo` is true, the commands evaluate to

```
+ cmd1 '&'
+ cmd2 '&'
+ cmd3 '&'
```

so the & is just another argument.

**Is there any other way to achieve this?** Besides code duplication, where I write if/then/else blocks with the different behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the if-else-clause to a function to avoid code duplication, e.g.:

```
function execute() {
    if [[ -n "$BGR" ]]; then
        "$@" &
    else
        "$@"
    fi
}

execute cmd1 arg1
execute cmd2 arg2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
eval cmd1 $BGR
eval cmd2 $BGR
eval cmd3 $BGR
wait
```